# how to get decimal values and special character using regex in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle11g

in my table has values like below and texts are in front and back text (not able to get value using  substring) decimal is not only like below.How to get these values from the specific columns

```
2.0GB/3.GB(not only GB  etc like many)
2.0/3.0 mp
2.0 GB/ 3.GB
2.0 /3.0 mp
2.0
2.0 mp
1
```

i used below query to get it is not work out for me . below query are

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '\d.*)
```

Comment: Check [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/Hr7hZU/1)

Comment: Does [it work for you](http://rextester.com/XEQO90236)?

Comment: thanks below are issues (some text)800 - 784(some text) -- this type is not coming only 800 is there
before the text, some of the digits are coming ex (text [1234] 1gb ) then it will reflect result as 1234

Comment: With such vague requirements, you cannot use a regex here.

Comment: if it is possible to remove digit inside [] in starting position

Comment: Yes, you can easily do that. [`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('[234] more text1','^\[[0-9]+]', '') from DUAL`](http://rextester.com/YSP7609).

Comment: Please provide exact requirements in the question.

Comment: in select query get values above mentioned values. in front and back of these values, there is text and numbers. I need to remove it.

Comment: What do you expect to get from the `(some text)800 - 784(some text)` entry? Check this approach if you need to remove them - http://rextester.com/XDZQ46745

Comment: above is solved by using below [0-9][.0-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*((/|-|\s)\s*[.?0-9][.0-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*)?

Comment: if it is possible to remove numbers in front of this regex

Comment: If [this code](http://rextester.com/FUPRZ79214) works for you, I will post with explanations.

Comment: it is work for me

Comment: one last question how to remove test with last word EG: 'abc1 1gb'

Comment: i want to remove 'abc1'

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'.*\s+', '')` or `REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'.*\s+(\S.*)', '\1')`

Comment: how to add this one on previous replace

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need. Please provide a sample input and expected output.

Comment: remove the text end with a number like 'abc1 1gb,tb1 1 gb,eard1 2 gb,help2 12 gb' i need last gb value only . add this condition in below regex  REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'\[[0-9]+]|[0-9]+\s*-\s*[0-9]+', ''), '[0-9][.0-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*(/\s*[0-9][.0-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*)?')

Comment: above one is possible

Comment: the problem is that in fact you do not need the last word, but several words that are closer to the end of the string. How can you determine that? In other languages, you could extract all matches and grab the last one. Here, you can't do that.

Comment: i dont need word ending with number

Comment: Ok, now you say you do not want the value after a "word" ending with a digit? But in your input string, the last `help2 12 gb` also contains the word with a number at the end. Maybe we can remove all up to the last comma?

Comment: i don't need help2 .i need 12 gb

Comment: Try [**the code from this demo**](http://rextester.com/IKFCOJ98951).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(s, '^.*,', ''),'\[[0-9]+]|[0-9]+\s*-\s*[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z][0-9]+', ''), '[0-9][.0-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*([-/]\s*[.?0-9][.0-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*)?')
```

The first step is removing all up to the last comma:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(s, '^.*,', '')
```

The second step is removing digit(s) inside square brackets, letters with digits after them and hyphen-separated ranges:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'\[[0-9]+]|[0-9]+\s*-\s*[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z][0-9]+', '')
```

Here, the pattern removes substrings matching:

- `\[` - a `[`
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `]` - a `]`
- `|` - or
- `[0-9]+\s*-\s*[0-9]+` - 1+ digits (`[0-9]+`), a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces and again 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `[a-zA-Z][0-9]+` - a letter with 1+ digits after it.

The third step is to extract the matches you need:

- `[0-9][.0-9]*` - a digit followed with 0+ digits or `.` symbols
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - 0+ letters
- `([-/]\s*[.?0-9][.0-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `[-/]` - a `-` or `/`
  - `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
  - `[.?0-9]` - `.`, `?` or digits
  - `[.0-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*`  - see above

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/IKFCOJ98951):

```
with test(s) as (
    select 'text [1234] 1gb' from dual union all
    select '(some text)800 - 784(some text) 2 Gb' from dual union all
    select '2.0GB/3.GB' from dual union all
    select '2.0/3.0 mp' from dual union all
    select '2.0 /3.0 mp' from dual union all
    select '2.0' from dual union all
    select '2.0 mp' from dual union all
    select '1' from dual union all
    select '2.0 GB/ 3.GB' from dual
)
select s, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(s, '^.*,', ''),'\[[0-9]+]|[0-9]+\s*-\s*[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z][0-9]+', ''), '[0-9][.0-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*([-/]\s*[.?0-9][.0-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*)?')
from test
```

Output:

```
1   abc1 1gb,tb1 1 gb,eard1 2 gb,help2 12 gb    12 gb
2   text [1234] 1gb                             1gb
3   (some text)800 - 784(some text) 2 Gb        2 Gb
4   2.0GB/3.GB                                  2.0GB/3.GB
5   2.0/3.0 mp                                  2.0/3.0 mp
6   2.0 /3.0 mp                                 2.0 /3.0 mp
7   2.0                                         2.0
8   2.0 mp                                      2.0 mp
9   1                                           1
10  2.0 GB/ 3.GB                                2.0 GB/ 3.GB
```